# Any other ways to do this?

Tags: java

I'm adding 2 intergers like a + b. But it gives me a invalid operation error. Any alternatives and also, I've already tried something like c = a + b but for this situation it won't work.

```
int add = 0;

    for (int a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
        if (a % 3 == 0) {
            add + a;
        } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
            add + a;
        }
        System.out.println(add);
    }
```

Are there any other ways or alternatives for + besides doing the c = a + b?

Comment: It gives repeats and I don't think it even works. @MadProgrammer

Comment: So what's the difference between it an `add = add + a`?  `add = add + a` and `add += a` is the same thing, if the calculation isn't giving you the results you expect, it's how you are using it that's wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm trying to add all the sums of the multiples of 3 and 5. That method gives different results.

Comment: @MadProgrammer is correct, you are currently performing an addition and throwing away the result, when you should be storing the result in your `add` variable. `add = add + a` means set the new value of `add` to the result of `add + a`. The shorthand for this operation is `add += a`.

Answer (score 0):

As Mad programmer said you need to be adding the value to add `add += a;`

```
int add = 0;

for (int a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
    if (a % 3 == 0) {
        add += a;
        System.out.println(add);
    } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
        add += a;
        System.out.println(add);
    }
}
```

and your comment

> It gives repeats and I don't think it even works

this was because you are outputting the total value in every loop with your print statement, you only want to output the value when you increase the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more concise (and correct) way to approach it:

```
int add = 0;
for (int a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
    if (a % 3 == 0 || a % 5 == 0) {
        add += a;
    } 
    System.out.println(add);
}
```

Note that:

```
add += a;
```

Is the same as:

```
add = add + a;
```